# How to start a simple Gradle+JavaFX+OSGi appliaction

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, javafx, osgi, bndtools

I'm trying to build a simple JavaFX application in IntelliJ environment using Gradle and OSGi, but I could't find a simple working example anywhere.
Most of the solutions I've found are not Gradle based or they use some additional tools, or they are outdated and they simply don't run, or they import some magical "hack code" from github etc.

The tools I've found for similar purpose e.g. e(fx)clipse, bndtools are probably not important if I use IntelliJ. Moreover the bndtools tutorial is very wordy and I couldn't find a good starting point or quickstart to try those things out.

I know the basics about Gradle and OSGi and according to information I've found, it does not seem to be an easy task to solve.
Are there any (good) tutorial(s) or quickstart(s) about how to start this kind of project properly? A simple working example would be very useful.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx ?

Comment: Not yet, thanks for the idea! I can see a pom.xml file in this project. Is it possible to make this framework Gradle compatible?

Comment: Don't know, the maintainer is mostly relying on maven-plugins for internal bundling, might not be that easy to "transport" it to gradle. Just contact the maintainer of the drombler-fx project.

Answer (score 0):

The e(fx)clipse project is a good starting point and provides many useful features for using JavaFX and OSGi.

See http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html .

The blog of one of the developers has also many useful tips, https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/ .